# <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC"....."> and <!DOCTYPE html> in eclipse

Tags: javascript, html, eclipse

Here is the html code of my question

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"></meta>
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var arr = [ "A", "B", "C" ];

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        document.write(arr[i]);;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

In the line `for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)` it shows the error`The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup a.`between '<' and 'arr.length'
If I cancel the space between '<' and 'arr.length',then it shows another error`Element type "arr.length" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".`
So consider that the code seems doesn't has any problems,then I try to change the "doctype" declaration of `<<!DOCTYPE html>`
And then everything goes well,now that I may can solve the problem with changing the doctype declaration.
But how can I do if the html file just must need the doctype declaration of `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">` and I also don't want it to shows the unnecessary errors?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `<![CDATA]` here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var arr = [ "A", "B", "C" ];

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        document.write(arr[i]);;
    }
    //]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks,I search the relative information about CDATA,is the js code being treated as not a  xml element when the code is in CDATA blocks?

Comment: @jacky You are right... CData is Content Data. `:)`